# Closing iframe so sound stops playing

Tags: html, audio, iframe

I can't find this and can't wrap my head around this.

I have a page with an iframe.  The iframe is set to play music (embedded sound file).  Then the iframe opens a page with a next button.  When the user hits the next button the page changes to another page with a next button too, but the sound file continues.  This is perfect, it does what I want it to do.

However,  after the user hits the second next button, a new iframe is loaded (to play a different sound file the spans over more than 3 pages.

The problem is the sound file from iframe1 is playing during iframe2.

I would appear that everything will play in the iframe1 once it is enabled.
How do I stop/close iframe1 so that only iframe2 will play?
Can I say something like (iframe1 run for 3 pages then iframe2 for 5 pages)?

to see what I mean go to https://dm2.ca/Second%20Coming%20of%20Christ/page38.html

Comment: I didn't see any iframe...there's a page named iframe...

Comment: Wow I can't even find the source of the music, I'm perplexed?!?